# Symfony2 Sonata Media Bundle Custom Image Cropping

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

It seems that Sonata Media has only two strategies when it comes to cropping/resizing the uploaded image, Sonata\MediaBundle\Resizer\SimpleResizer and Sonata\MediaBundle\Resizer\SquareResizer. Both these strategies are automatic, meaning that the users don't have a say in how they want the image to be resized/croppped.

I would like to give the user an option to select the portion of the image that is more relevant, kind like the jQuery Image Cropper library used by GenemuFormBundle, but I don't even know where to start. Will I need to create my own Admin class instead of using Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin? Has anyone write a bundle that I can use? How do you manage your galleries usually?

[image]

Comment: Give it a try and let me know [*`Sonata Media Crop`*](https://github.com/dianuj89/Sonata-Media-Crop)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [ComurImageBundle](https://github.com/comur/ComurImageBundle). It's far easier than Sonata Media, doesn't create anything in database and lets you upload with jquery file uploader, crop with jcrop and other useful things.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple admin extension that give you the ability to customize the images by format. It's actually  a Work In Progress that needs some test, documentation and refactoring, but it does the job, it's lightweight and it's shipped with a resizer to handle fixed dimensions.

You can find it here: https://github.com/julien-maitan/sonata-media-crop

Answer (score -1):

If you are using sonata media bundle with sonata admin, there is a picasa photo editor already in place in media edit form.

Please check.